# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' when try to do a difference between two arrays

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hello I have the following code:

```
const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])
const [zProjects, setZProjects] = useState([])


const loadZProjects: any = async () => {   
    await Axios.get(`${url}/z/get_info?projects`)
    .then((res) => {
      const gProjects:string[] = projects
      const newZProjects = res.data.projects.filter((x:string) => { return graphProjects.indexOf(x) < 0 })
      setZProjects(newZProjects)
    })
    .catch((err) => err?.response?.status === 404 && {})  
  }
```

And In the lines

```
const gProjects:string[] = projects
          const newZProjects = res.data.projects.filter((x:string) => { return graphProjects.indexOf(x) < 0 })
```

I get the following error:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'never'

But if I use this

```
const newZonificatorProjects = res.data.projects.filter((x:string) => { return projects.indexOf(x) < 0 })
```

I got the same error.

So how can I solve that in order to get set difference between projects and zprojects?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that ````gProjects```` and response of api are correct format before making filter operation?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WJq7gm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: the res.data or res.data.projects can be null. You can check the truthify condition --  `const newZProjects = (res.data && res.data.projects) ? (res.data.projects.filter((x:string) => { return graphProjects.indexOf(x) < 0 }) : []);`

Comment: the two projects arrays are arrays of string or empty arrays

Comment: You need to give `useState` a generic - `[]` is inferred as `never[]` automatically. It is complaining that you are giving it something other than `never` for the state. For example, `useState<string[]>([]);` will allow me to use an array of strings.